# Swift optional property take memory space?

Tags: swift, memory

1. Does the properties in a class take any memory space? I think should be yes.
2. How much space was taken by optional type?
3. If the property has a default value, is it take more space then optional type?

Like below:

```
class Person {
    var name: String?
}

class Person1 {
    var name1: String = ""
}

class Person2 {
    var name2: String = "Jim"
}

class Person3 {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

When I defined these variables, does `person2` will take more space? Or they are all take same spaces.

```
let person = Person()
let person1 = Person1()
let person2 = Person2()
let person3 = Person3(name:"Jack")
```

How about other variables? I think if I use `UIImage` then init with an Image like:

```
let image = UIImage(name: "abc.png")
```

It must be take some space.

Why I ask this is I saw some code is like:

```
var name: String = ""
```

I think should be use optional string for no default value.

Thank you for your answer!

**EDIT**
For question 1: Apple's ARC said:

> Every time you create a new instance of a class, ARC allocates a chunk
>   of memory to store information about that instance. This memory holds
>   information about the type of the instance, together with the values
>   of any stored properties associated with that instance.

so my first question should be **YES**.

**EDIT 2**

All the output is 8:

```
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:person2)
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:person1)
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:person)
```

even I add more properties to the class.

**EDIT 3**

```
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:"good") // Output: 24

var ok:String?
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:ok) // Output: 25


var ok1: String? = "good"
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:ok) // Output: 25
```

**EDIT4**

```
class Person4 {
    var name: String = "good"
    let image = UIImage(named: "no")
}

let person4 = Person4()
MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:person4) // Output is 8
```

I think my questions are all answered. My still not clear like EIDT4 the output is still 8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463400/in-swift-should-i-set-my-optional-instance-variables-to-nil-when-done this might shed some light

Comment: This seems like premature optimization. This won't make a difference. Check this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout